# How to view the downloaded document directly from the new tab?

Tags: java

i need to show my attached document on my received mail or some file(doc) which was located at server side, on separate new tab or window in browser.
For example: in gmail if we got any mail with some attachment file like doc, their we can see two options like view and download. In my requirement i want that functionality when user had click on View link, the attached file will open on separate tab...... ru got my point friends.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? its hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a server side page which will be presenting the document in html format. Note that this document will have never been downloaded to the client. It will be a regular server side page, like the rest of your application.

Regarding presentation of this page in a new tab or window, this is client side functionality. The closest you can get to opening a new tab is to use `<a href="#" target="_blank">...</a>`.